# How to create and use a XML document object properly considering browser compatibility?

Tags: javascript, xml, browser

Now I'm working on a web project. I need to create a XML document object using a given string buffer in JavaScript. I've successfully made it run smoothly on IE, but apparently I need to do some more work to improve its compatibility.

Here is a tiny example describing what I want to express (Note, all in JavaScript)
first of all, we have a string variable, say, "buffer", which has been obtained from the server and, in fact, it is formed like a XML:

```
"<Messages><Item>aaa</Item><Item>bbb</Item></Messages>"
```

Then, I can use the following code segment to create a IE-recognizable XML doc object:

```
var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.xmlDOM");
xmlDoc.async = false;
xmlDoc.loadXML(buffer);
```

And we've got it.

So, what I want to know is how to create an object considering browser compatibility (firefox, opera, etc) and whether the usages of it are same.

Comment: I'm sorry about the mistake: "it is formed like a XML: 'aaabbb' "
The system ignored my XML tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOMParser) should work. It is not a standard, but it is supported at least on WebKit (Safari, Chrome, etc), and Gecko (Firefox); I don't know about Opera:

```
var buffer = "<Messages><Item>aaa</Item><Item>bbb</Item></Messages>";
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(buffer, "text/xml");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works.
What's more, you edit the answer for me. It's kind of you!