# Can OpenLayers parse GPX data which is stored as a string in a javascript variable?

Tags: openlayers, gpx

I have a map site using OpenLayers, which imports and displays GPX data using the following code:

```
var lgpx = new OpenLayers.Layer.GML(gpxtracktitle, gpxfileaddress, {

  format: OpenLayers.Format.GPX,

  style: {strokeColor: plmapvars.colourarray[i%7], strokeWidth: 5, strokeOpacity: 0.7},

  projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
});

map.addLayer(lgpx);
```

I'm looking for a way to display gpx data which, rather than being stored as a file, is saved as a string in a javascript variable:

```
var gpxstring ="<?xml ... </gpx>"
```

I've tried passing the string into the code above as a data uri, without success.  Is OpenLayers capable of parsing GPX from a string in the way I'm attempting to do it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe there is an easier way, but here you go:

You already know about [`OpenLayers.format.GPX` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Format/GPX-js.html). It has a `read` method, which accepts an XML document and returns an array of features. You can then add those feature to a layer.

How to parse the XML string and create an XML document is described in [How to create and use a XML document object properly considering browser compatibility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790370/how-to-create-and-use-a-xml-document-object-properly-considering-browser-compati)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've set up the xml parsing as described in the link and it is producing an XML object successfully.

The OpenLayers method is not especially well documented, so that will probably take me a fair bit more work to get it functioning, but I think this method is the way to go.